# Sudden PC Hard Restart

Tags: windows-7

I was recently working on my computer and all of a sudden My computer died. Like I held the power button in for a hard turn off. Then my computer restarted. I check the comp temp when I get back to windows and i says it is at 45 degrees. I've had this happen now 5 times in as many days. I'm running Windows 7 64-bit any ideas? I'm a bit of a novice at this.

Answer (score 0):

Possible things to check:

- Replace your power supply (or clean it!).
- Add a UPS or surge arrester to filter your incoming power.

When your computer reboots on it's own like that the usual cause is a power blip.